# How do I set the position of a JLabel 130px next to an existing one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, layout-manager

I am creating a new label which I want to position precisely 130px next to an existing one. I am not familiar with layouts and would rather absolutely position my labels. My code is as follows:

```
 playerLabels[index] = new javax.swing.JLabel();
 playerLabels[index].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/image001".png")));
 playerLabels[index].setBounds(playerLabels[index - 1].getX() + 130, playerLabels[index - 1].getY(), playerLabels[index - 1].getWidth(), playerLabels[index - 1].getHeight());

 panel.add(playerLabels[index]);
 playerLabels[index].setVisible(true);
```

I am not getting any errors, but even though my labels are created. They do not appear at the desired position.

Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: Use a layout.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/.

Comment: `I am not familiar with layouts` - now is a good time to learn. `would rather absolutely position my labels` - Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. By trying to manage the location manually you are in effect reinventing the wheel. There are different ways to position components. You could add a Border around your label that is 130 pixels. You could add an invisible component between the two labels that is 130 pixels. Without a proper requirement we can't suggest the best solution.

Comment: Once situation when you might use a null layout is when you have "random" positioning of a component because the user can drag a component or you have animation of a component as the component is moved by a Swing Timer. But you have a specific requirement of 130 pixels which implies it is not random.

Comment: Or maybe use a FlowLayout. You can specify a gap of 130 pixels between each component. Or use a GridLayout you can specify a gap and all components will be the same size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree that it's usually better to use a LayoutManager. That said, here's an article Oracle posted that describes how to do this:
[Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Comment: `I ended up reading on Layouts. Thank you for the link` - you were given the link 5 hours ago in the first comment.

Answer (score -2):

The code that you have posted will not depict the issue. Please give a sample code that can replicate your problem.

To address your problem, if you set the position of element manually (setBounds), you need to first set the container layout null and secondly you need to set the size of panel where you are adding those jlabel.

1.

`this.setLayout(null);`

2.

`panel.setSize(900,900); // whatever the size you need.`

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. The problem can be solved with proper usage of layout managers.

Comment: @camickr Please check my answer again. I am not recommending to setLyout null but if someone wants to use setBounds, he has to use setLayout null. What's wrong in it. Obviously he can use any existing standard layout for component but that's another question.

Comment: *"What's wrong in it."* I'm not @camickr, but any suggestion of using a `null` layout will get an automatic down-vote from me. By the time a programmer is in a position to use null layouts, they should be skilled enough in use of standard layout managers to realize 1) When to (and when not to) use a null layout. 2) That custom layout logic is best described in a `CustomLayout` than as random code written for a null layout container. -- Suggesting null layouts to newbies tends to have them deciding that is the best (spoiler: it's not) or only way to make a GUI.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion @AndrewThompson. I also won't give suggestion to set layout null. However what I was trying to explain him that setBounds doesn't work unless you set the layout null. Lampros  was wondering why even after setting  position by using setBounds, it's not showing up at desired position. So the reason was layout.

Comment: You keep coming back to "but they asked", so let me share a comment relevant to my earlier point.. See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)